# examples of not monotonic sequences which diverge to infinity i.e. sn tends to infinity as n tends to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

What examples are there of sequences which are not monotonic that diverge to positive infinity ?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, those sequences do not diverge to infinity in the common sense of the word.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Apparently, I read series instead of sequence.

Comment: Let $a_n$ be a monotonic sequence that diverges to $\infty$.  Let $b_{2n}=a_n$ and $b_{2n+1}=a_n-1$.  Then the sequence diverges to $\infty$, but the terms are not always increasing $(b_{2n+1}<b_{2n})$.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBurr - intuitively I understand this simple clear example. My query is, does this meet the standard definition of divergence? I'm no expert, but the definition I understand is that a divergent sequence will eventually grow larger than any value we think of, which your non-monotonic sequence does.

Answer (score 3):

E.g.
$$
s_n = n + 2(-1)^n. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$s_n = \cases{n^2 & if $n$ is even \\ n^3 & if $n$ is odd }$$